# What is the relationship between the notation and engraving tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I'm unclear on how we use these two tags.

I think we could potentially get rid of the [engraving](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engraving) tag and only use [notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation), but I also wonder if some questions really *do* deserve the [engraving](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engraving) tag.

The closest question I've found that may deserve the [engraving](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engraving) tag is [Is there a standard source for music engraving?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/49761/is-there-a-standard-source-for-music-engraving) But even then, I don't think we as a community lose anything if this question's [engraving](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engraving) tag were to disappear and instead only had the [notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation) tag.

What do we think? Should we do away with the [engraving](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/engraving) tag and make it a synonym that points to [notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notation)? Or are there clear instances where we would need the two separate tags?

Comment: I think as a site we could make the distinction between general notation questions and questions about engraving techniques. For example someone asking what does this mark mean has no intent on engraving while how to decided which way stems point is more engraving than notation

Comment: Perhaps the engraving tag could get a better description, so as to distinguish the two tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Notation' should be about WHAT you want to see on the paper.

'Engraving' is about HOW to get it there.  These days, it will mostly be about technique in the various notation programs.

Answer (score 1):

Whereas notation is about the *meaning* of the various signs and symbols,
engraving is more about *where* and *when* to place them.